# Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM) With Dry Friction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Consider a mass $m$ at position $x(t)$ on a rough horizontal table attached to the origin by a spring with constant $k$ (restoring force $−kx$) and with a dry friction force $f$

\begin{equation}
f=
\begin{cases}
 F\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \,\,\,\, x<0\\
-F \leq f \leq F \quad \quad x = 0\\
 -F \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

What is the range of $x$ where the mass can rest? Show that if the mass moves, the maximum excursion decreases by
$2F/k$ per half cycle. Discuss the motion.

Up until now i have only dealt with SHM with no friction so I am a bit lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your friction term is not written correctly, you have two cases for $x>0$.

Comment: See [this](https://www.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/MarchewkaAbbott&Beichner.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Some Hints**

The governing differential equation according to Newton's second law of motion will be

$$\begin{cases}
- kx - F  = m\ddot x & \dot x \gt 0 \\
- kx + F  = m\ddot x & \dot x \lt 0
 \end{cases}$$

If $\dot x=0$ then we should investigate that whether the particle moves or not due to the laws of static and kinetic friction. Rearranging the terms will give

$$\begin{cases}
\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x = - \frac{F}{k} & \dot x \gt 0 \\
\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x =  \frac{F}{k} & \dot x \lt 0
 \end{cases}$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ is the natural frequency. The general solution to this ODE is

$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = A \cos (\omega t) + B \sin (\omega t) - \frac{F}{k} & \dot x \gt 0 \\
x(t) = A \cos (\omega t) + B \sin (\omega t) + \frac{F}{k} & \dot x \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

Try to discuss the problem based on initial conditions.

---

**Reference**

[Here is a nice article](https://www.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/MarchewkaAbbott&Beichner.pdf) that you can refer to it. It explains everything from A to Z. You can take a look at **part IV**. There is a little mistake in equations 22a, 22b and 23a, 23b. The $\dot{x}$ should be written instead of $\ddot{x}$ for the signs. The text mentions this issue by words right above equations 22a, 22b so it seems to be a simple typo.

Comment: Could you provide a complete solution?

Comment: @RSparkes: I added more hints. I want you to solve it by your self. :)

Comment: You solution is incorrect as it's discontinuous. Also $sgn'=2\delta\ne 0$.

Comment: What does F and f signify, also what is a dry friction force? Also what is sgn?

Comment: @A.S.: Maybe you are right but I should think more. :) However, we are taking the derivative with respect to $t$ and not $\dot x$! Physically, we have a force that its direction depends on the sign of velocity. Please feel free to edit my answer if you are sure about something or post a new answer that we can learn from it. :)

Comment: I'm more like a verification oracle in this case ;) (who is only sure that your "general solution to this ODE" is off as it's discontinuous). Sidenote: $(sgn(\dot x))'=\delta(\dot x)\ddot{x}$

Comment: @A.S.: OK oracle! :) Suffice it to say at this point, my derivations are only valid for $\dot x \ne 0$! :) I will try to think more about it. :) This is a famous problem and I think I have seen before! :)

Comment: @RSparkes: Take a look at the updated answer. Hope this finally helps. :)